# warnings when dealing with format specifier %llu

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, sizeof, format-specifiers, size-t

Just a new programmer here.

I was experimenting with `size_t` and `sizeof`, specifically using them to find the size of an array, cause I was trying to make an array with the number of indexes be changeable.

Code:

```
int main() {

    int index = 0;

    printf("Enter size of an array: ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    int MyArray[index];

    size_t capacity = sizeof(MyArray)/sizeof(MyArray[0]);

    printf("\nThe length of your array is: %llu", capacity);

    return 0;
}
```

And if you look at the `printf` statement, you can see that I used a format specifier which is `%llu` for `long long unsigned int` because (if I'm right) it was the data type of `size_t`.

But then it gives me multiple warnings like:

```
warning: unknown conversion type character 'l' in format [-Wformat=]|
warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]|
```

Comment: Please use the correct format specifier `%zu`, although `%llu` is a valid format spec. Aside: it is unclear why you need to compute the length of an array that you just defined to have `index` elements.

Comment: Did you **copy/paste** the *exact* code that gave the error about `l`?

Answer (score 2):

> And if you look at the `printf` statement, you can see that I used a format specifier which is `%llu` for `long long unsigned int` because (if I'm right) it was the data type of `size_t`.

Clearly that is not right. Some C implementations may use `long long unsigned int` for `size_t`, but yours does not.

The C standard specifies a `printf` format flag for the `size_t` type, `z`, so `%zu` is a correct conversion specifier to use for `size_t` in any C implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As for the obtained warnings then this conversion specifier `%llu`  as is is written correctly. Maybe these warnings are consequences of some other message that an incorrect conversion specifier with a value of the type `size_t` is used.

Also some very old compilers do not support types `long long int` and `unsigned long long int`.As a result the conversion specifier `llu` was not introduced.

However in any case you are using an invalid conversion specifier with a value of the type `size_t`.

From the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> 4 The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

Usually the type `size_t` is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long int`. The rank of the type `unsigned long long int` is greater than the rank of the type `unsigned long int` (that is the same as the rank of the type `signed long int`).

For example in Microsoft C the `sizeof( unsigned long long int )` is equal to `8` while `sizeof( unsigned long int )` and `sizeof( size_t )` are equal to `4`.  And moreover the type `size_t` is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned int` instead of the usually used type `unsigned long`.

And from the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 7 The length modifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **z** **Specifies that a following d, i, o, u, x, or X conversion specifier applies to a size_t** or the corresponding signed integer
> type argument; or that a following n conversion specifier applies to a
> pointer to a signed integer type corresponding to size_t argument.

So to output objects of the type `size_t` you should use the conversion specifier `zu`.

And

> 9 **If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined**. If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Thus you should write

```
printf("\nThe length of your array is: %zu", capacity);
                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: How does this answer the question about the *unknown* format specifier?

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if the OP miscopied it from the actual code, where it might have been a typo of say `%l1u`. It would not be the first time that code in a book was miscopied with a `1` where an `l` should be.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did try "%zu" and it now said z was an unknown conversion type.

Comment: @Kryspin It seems you are using a very old compiler. In this case use the conversion specifier %lu.